# Não consigo retornar o url de uma imagem android

Tags: android, kotlin

Estou utilizando o seguinte código para gravar dados e imagens no firebase e está ate funcionando, mas o link da imagem não estou conseguindo captar.

```
var uploadTesk: UploadTask = imageRef.putBytes(dadosImage!!);


        uploadTesk.addOnFailureListener(object: OnFailureListener{
            override fun onFailure(p0: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Error ao enviar imagem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }).addOnSuccessListener(object:OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>{
            override fun onSuccess(p0: UploadTask.TaskSnapshot?) {

                imageRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener(object:OnSuccessListener<Uri> {
                    override fun onSuccess(p0: Uri?) {
                        **newItemMenu.photoItem = p0.toString()**;
                    }

                }).addOnFailureListener(object: OnFailureListener{
                    override fun onFailure(p0: Exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, p0.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                })

                //Save menu
                if ( newItemMenu.save() ){
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Sucesso ao cadastrar produto!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        })
```

Onde tem **newItemMenu.photoItem = p0.toString();** ele não adiciona a url na minha classe para ser salva, ja usei o log e toast ele mostrar a url certinha mas não está passando o valor para classe salvar no banco..
Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Coloca o salvar dentro da TASK para pegar a URL

```
        var uploadTesk: UploadTask = imageRef.putBytes(dadosImage!!);


    uploadTesk.addOnFailureListener(object: OnFailureListener{
        override fun onFailure(p0: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Error ao enviar imagem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }).addOnSuccessListener(object:OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>{
        override fun onSuccess(p0: UploadTask.TaskSnapshot?) {

            imageRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener(object:OnSuccessListener<Uri> {
                override fun onSuccess(p0: Uri?) {
                    **newItemMenu.photoItem = p0.toString()**;
                    //Save menu
                    if ( newItemMenu.save() ){
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Sucesso ao cadastrar produto!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

            }).addOnFailureListener(object: OnFailureListener{
                override fun onFailure(p0: Exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, p0.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            })


        }

    })
```